# How to show midnight time in DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently stuck on trying to display midnight time for my DataFrame. Things I have tried are:

```
df.set_index('PCTimeStamp       ', inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.tz_convert('UTC')


datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") for x in t_s]


pd.to_datetime(df['PCTimeStamp       '], format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M" )
```

My time in the column looks something like this:

```
8/23/2017
8/23/2017 0:10
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dt.normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
df['PCTimeStamp'].dt.normalize()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I figured out the solution accidentally. df['PCTimeStamp       '] = pd.to_datetime(df['PCTimeStamp       ']) will show midnight.

Comment: @eemamedo no it won't! That'll parse hours and seconds too.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So I am trying to get rid of seconds now. But your solution returns "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" error

Comment: @eemamedo you need to ensure the column is a datetime, which means you _first_ need to do `df['PCTimeStamp '] = pd.to_datetime(df['PCTimeStamp ']) `, or df['PCTimeStamp '] = pd.to_datetime(df['PCTimeStamp ']).normalize()